# In a SQL query (DB2), how can I find a field value within another field?

Tags: sql, db2

In a SQL query (DB2), how can I find a field value within another field?
For example, Field01 contains part number '1234'. Field02 contains 'this is my 1234 to keep'

How can I find or search for whatever is the value of Field01 within Field02?

I've tried LOCATE and LIKE and % % and Position but cannot seem to get it.

I have been able to find Field01 in Field02 as long as it is in the beginning of Field02, but not if it is proceeded by other characters.
This is the command I've used for this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN LEFT ( TRIM ( FIELD02), CHARACTER_LENGTH ( TRIM ( FIELD01 ) ) ) =  
     TRIM ( WMCPIL ) THEN TRIM ( FIELD02) 
 ELSE '^' 
END
```

Comment: Did you try `CONTAINS`?

Comment: Edit your question and show an example that you tried using the `LOCATE` function. `LOCATE(field01,field02)` should return non-zero if found and zero if not found.

Answer (score 2):

The `LOCATE` function should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE LOCATE(field01,field02) <> 0
```

Your question states that you already tried `LOCATE`; if it did not work, please explain.

[Here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/flocate.htm) is a documentation reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` in following manner:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE field2 LIKE '%' || field1 || '%'
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c14d2/1) (using PostgreSQL as SQLFiddle does not support DB2 yet, but this example should work on DB2 as well).

DB2 prefers to use `CONCAT` to concatenate strings, but it also supports standard `||` as a synonym.

Comment: 'LIKE' seems to have issues in DB2 when the right-side expression contains a column name.  That might cause issues with the comparison.

Comment: FWiW: The origin for *issues* in such scenarios I have seen, are typically per the use of a field that is a fixed-length character data type rather than varying-length, but the intention was that the search should be on the trimmed or stripped value of that field; i.e. rather than `LIKE '%' || field1 || '%'`, often the desired effect was achieved instead, with either a `LIKE '%' || RTRIM(field1) || '%'` or the more aggressive stripping\trimming of `LIKE '%' || TRIM(field1) || '%'`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, try it-

SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE POSITION(field1,field2,CODEUNITS16)<>0